# Mercury fails to rise in thermometer

Tags: medical-device, thermometer

I have a mercury (`Hg`) thermometer manufactured by Ballo Thermometers (in Leesburg, Florida) circa May 1969.  On the backside is printed “MICH 42”, which is apparently the name of its stereotype.

The mercury fails to rise from out of the tip.
I tried heating to excess of 106°F, but to no avail.
I can see the mercury in the empty channel on the tip's side of the bottleneck to the uniform tube with the calibrated marks — if I can aquire use of a photographic lens with adequate resolution, I will be able to show photographs.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea why. I'd be interested in the answer as well. Hope that it attracts some attention...

Comment: Is it possible there's a crack somewhere and enough mercury has leaked out over the years that there's now room for it to expand so it doesn't rise?

Comment: @CareyGregory Good thought, but unlikely:  I don't see or feel any gaps or cracks; due to surface tension, I'd expect that any crack large enough to allow the mercury to escape would've drained all of it, but there does appear to be some in the tube.